# Meaning of the symbol

Tags: identification, components, symbol

[image]

What's the meaning of this symbol?

[image]

Comment: "PZ1" implies a piezo device of some kind.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks.Really helpful to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an ultrasonic piezo transducer, a 113 kHz piezo buzzer, although I don't know if you can call it a buzzer if you can't hear it. It is used here in what looks like a mist maker.

Comment: A piezo ultrasonic transducer then?

Comment: @ocrdu Yes, I am making sprayers for the dry weather in winter.I appreciate your talent very much. Your ability to know its usefulness through the circuit diagram is really great.I hope that one day I will have this ability。